# How to convert a boxed array into a Vec in Rust

Tags: rust

I have a boxed array of structs and I want to consume this array and insert it into a vector.

My current approach would be to convert the array into a vector, but the corresponding library function does not seem to work the way I expected.

```
let foo = Box::new([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let bar = foo.into_vec();
```

The compiler error states

> no method named `into_vec` found for type `Box<[_; 4]>` in the current scope

I've found specifications [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) that look like

```
fn into_vec(self: Box<[T]>) -> Vec<T>
Converts self into a vector without clones or allocation.
```

... but I am not quite sure how to apply it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation you link to](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) is for slices, i.e., `[T]`, while what you have is an array of length 4: `[T; 4]`.

You can, however, simply convert those, since an array of length 4 *kinda is* a slice. This works:

```
let foo = Box::new([1, 2, 3, 4]);
let bar = (foo as Box<[_]>).into_vec();
```

Comment: It is strange that a method for a completely different self type `Box<[T]>` can be defined in an `impl Vec<T>`. Is that documented somewhere? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_vec

Comment: @starblue As far as I see, the method used here is this one: http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.into_vec

Comment: @Thierry Maybe, then `Box` is added to `Self` like a reference. The one on `Vec` is still strange.

Answer (score 9):

I think there's more cleaner way to do it. When you initialize `foo`, add type to it. [Playground](http://is.gd/fiye66)

```
fn main() {
    let foo: Box<[u32]> = Box::new([1, 2, 3, 4]);
    let bar = foo.into_vec();

    println!("{:?}", bar);
}
```

Comment: So it is better that you are loosing the length information?

Comment: @fyaa I think there's no need for length information in your example when you allocating your slice. You are not losing anything. This is not a fixed-size array, but a slice.

Comment: The length of the slice is encoded into the pointer to the slice (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754901/what-is-a-fat-pointer).  No information is being lost.