# Why I can use dynamic dispatch with Rc but not RefCell?

Tags: rust

I was using `Rc` for dynamic dispatch on an object that implements a trait. Then I needed interior mutability so I changed to `RefCell`. I thought that `RefCell` was simply an `Rc` for interior mutability, but it won't accept my trait object.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait Test {}

struct A;

impl Test for A {}

fn main() {
    // This works:
    let x: Rc<dyn Test> = Rc::new(A);
    
    // But this not:
    // let x: RefCell<dyn Test> = RefCell::new(A);
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:18:32
   |
18 |     let x: RefCell<dyn Test> = RefCell::new(A);
   |            -----------------   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected trait object `dyn Test`, found struct `A`
   |            |
   |            expected due to this
   |
   = note: expected struct `std::cell::RefCell<dyn Test>`
              found struct `std::cell::RefCell<A>`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn Test` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
18 |     let x: RefCell<dyn Test> = RefCell::new(A);
   |         ^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: within `std::cell::RefCell<dyn Test>`, the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `dyn Test`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
   = note: required because it appears within the type `std::cell::RefCell<dyn Test>`
   = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
   = help: unsized locals are gated as an unstable feature
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A `RefCell` is a wrapper struct facilitating interior mutability, while an `Rc` is a reference-counted smart pointer. They are quite different and serve orthogonal purposes. If you want to use a trait object with interior mutability, you can combine `Rc` and `RefCell` to `Rc<RefCell<dyn Test>>`.

A `RefCell` provides a safe mechanism to borrow the wrapped value at runtime. Rust's requirements for references – mutable borrows are exclusive – are checked when you use the `borrow()` or `borrow_mut()` methods based on a flag stored in the `RefCell` alongside the wrapped value.

An `Rc` is a reference-counted smart pointer. It allows multiple owners for a heap-allocated value. Once all references are dropped, the pointee will be deallocated. As you can see, this functionality is unrelated to checking borrows at runtime.

If you wrap a dynamically sized type like a trait object inside a `RefCell`, you end up with a dynamically sized `RefCell`. In Rust, dynamically sized types cannot be stored on the stack, so you have to put it behind some kind of reference. In this case `Rc` seems most appropriate, since a `RefCell` is most useful when combined with shared ownership.

Related question:

- [What is a fat pointer in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754901/what-is-a-fat-pointer-in-rust)

This section in the book provides further explanations:

- [Having Multiple Owners of Mutable Data by Combining `Rc<T>` and `RefCell<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html?highlight=refcell#having-multiple-owners-of-mutable-data-by-combining-rct-and-refcellt)