# Copy big value from Box into Vec in Rust without blowing the stack

Tags: memory-management, rust, stack-overflow

I want to copy (not move) a very big value from a box into a vec. The normal way of doing this (dereferencing the box) means the value is copied onto the stack temporarily, which blows it. Here's an example and a Playground link where it can be reproduced.

```rust
fn main() {
    let big_value = Box::new([0u8; 8 * 1024 * 1024]);
    let mut vec = Vec::new();
    vec.push(*big_value);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5998cff185dc209e7a1e676d41850ff4

Since both the Box and the Vec are on the heap, it should be possible to do a copy without passing through the stack. What's the best solution here?

Comment: Not exactly a solution, but: Recent nightly versions of Rust should no longer suffer from this problem at all because LLVM is now smart enough to avoid the stack altogether. The playground successfully executes on nightly.

Comment: Isn't there a problem with the first line `Box::new([0u8; 8 * 1024 * 1024]);` too ?

Comment: no there is not (without unsafe), the correct solution is to avoid this, but as other said this is optimized out on nightly

Comment: Good to know. Looks like you need the release flag as well though - I'm going to hold out for another solution, because I'd like to continue using debug builds.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use `big_value.into_vec()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35751927/how-to-convert-a-boxed-array-into-a-vec-in-rust

Comment: Please clarify: do you want the resulting `Vec` to be a `Vec<[u8; 8388608]>` of length 1, or a `Vec<u8>` of length 8388608?

Comment: Like it says in the example - a `Vec<u8; 8388608>` of length 1.

Answer (score 3):

See this answer on a Reddit post I made: https://old.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/n2jasd/question_copy_big_value_from_box_into_vec_without/gwmrcxp/

You can do this with `vec.extend_from_slice(std::slice_from_ref(&big_value));`. This performs no allocations, and just copies the `big_value` from the heap into a new slot in the vec.